# Mock system call in ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking

Know of a way to mock %[]? I'm writing tests for code that makes a few system calls, for example:

```
def log(file)
  %x[git log #{file}]
end
```

and would like to avoid actually executing system calls while testing this method. Ideally I'd like to mock %x[..] and assert that the correct shell command is passed to it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`%x{…}` is Ruby built-in syntax that will actually call Kernel method [Backtick (`)](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005960). So you can redefine that method. As backtick method returns the standard output of running cmd in a subshell, your redefined method should return something similar to that ,for example, a string.

```
module Kernel
    def `(cmd)
        "call #{cmd}"
    end
end

puts %x(ls)
puts `ls`
# output
# call ls
# call ls
```

Answer (score 14):

Using [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/), if you want to mock to following class:

```
class Test
  def method_under_test
    system "echo 'Hello World!"
    `ls -l`
  end
end
```

your test would look something like:

```
def test_method_under_test
  Test.any_instance.expects(:system).with("echo 'Hello World!'").returns('Hello World!').once
  Test.any_instance.expects(:`).with("ls -l").once
end
```

This works because every object inherits methods like system and ` from the Kernel object.

Comment: Using `should_receive` instead of `expects`

Comment: Doesn't work with the current version. Minitest::UnexpectedError: NoMethodError: undefined method `any_instance' for Test:Module; However, it worked if I called it on the object.

Comment: Yes, the pitfall is that `expects(:\`)` should be called on the class which makes the system call, but not on `Kernel`.

Comment: Same here Velizar, and thanks for the comment.  Adding that I am using Ruby 2.1.5 with Rails 3.2.22.1.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to mock a module, I'm afraid. With Mocha at least, `Kernel.expects` doesn't help. You *could* always wrap the calling in a class and mock that, something like this:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'mocha'

class SystemCaller
  def self.call(cmd)
    system cmd
  end
end

class TestMockingSystem < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_mocked_out_system_call
    SystemCaller.expects(:call).with('dir')
    SystemCaller.call "dir"
  end
end
```

which gives me what I'd hope for:

```
Started
.
Finished in 0.0 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

How about logging it to a text file, or outputting it to your console?

```
def log(file)
  puts "git log #{file}"
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Can't you just ovverride the function with a method that returns true when it gets the command?