# Ruby - FlexMock Backticks Method

Tags: ruby

I have Ruby code that uses the backticks in a number of spots and want to test it out. I'm using [FlexMock](http://flexmock.rubyforge.org/) and want to mock that method somehow. I know the method is [Kernel, :`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005960) but can't seem to get it to work with FlexMock. How would you do this? Here's a sample of a method I want to test:

```
def foo
  result = `ls`
  if result.to_a.length > 0
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out the backticks method specifically maps to Kernel.`, which is fine until one looks at the FlexMock source to see what they consider to be valid method names. The regex they use essentially is checking for alphanumeric with ? or ! at the end, so backtick fails to match this regex.

Changing the code internally resolves the initial exception that is thrown, but doesn't actually make the code work as intended. I could have monkeypatched it as pierr suggested, but that would be extremely repetitive in my testing code, so I went the alternate route and just made a shell method in my library code that only does the backticks. This method then can be mocked out in the desired fashion, and since I only use the backticks in a small number of places, not a lot of my underlying code had to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about flexmock, but you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628586/mock-system-call-in-ruby/1628848#1628848).

Comment: Hmm, I could use something similar to this, but it makes a lot of work that flexmock is designed to get around. Part of the problem is that the ` method is just named differently than standard methods so flexmock's internal regex doesn't think it's a real method, but +1 for the good idea though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
Kernel.` "cmd"
```

instead of using

```
  `cmd`
```

on your code. Then you can test like this:

```
it "should call system ls" do
  Kernel.should_receive(:`).with("ls")
  Kernel.` "ls"
end
```

this example uses pure rspec

Comment: Yes, as my answer says though, flexmock doesn't allow for backticks to be in mocked method names, so while it may work for rspec, it doesn't work for flexmock. Thanks though!