# How do I stub/mock a call to the command line with rspec?

Tags: ruby, command-line, rspec

I'm trying to test output from a command line tool. How do I 'fake' a command line call with rspec? Doing the following doesn't work:

```
it "should call the command line and return 'text'" do
  @p = Pig.new
  @p.should_receive(:run).with('my_command_line_tool_call').and_return('result text')
end
```

How do I create that stub?

Comment: Can we see the relevant pieces of the `Pig` class?

Comment: There's [this](https://gist.github.com/matthijsgroen/5669777) (have not used it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick example I made. I call *ls* from my dummy class. Tested with rspec

```
require "rubygems"
require "spec"

class Dummy
  def command_line
    system("ls")
  end
end

describe Dummy do
  it  "command_line should call ls" do
    d = Dummy.new
    d.should_receive("system").with("ls")
    d.command_line
  end
end
```

Comment: I think I had some other prohibitive bugs that weren't even getting to the run/system call.

Comment: How is this stubbing or mocking the system call?

Answer (score 11):

Using the [new message expectation syntax](http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/):

## spec/dummy_spec.rb

```
require "dummy"

describe Dummy do
  it "command_line should call ls" do
    d = Dummy.new
    expect(d).to receive(:system).with("ls")
    d.command_line
  end
end
```

## lib/dummy.rb

```
class Dummy
  def command_line
    system("ls")
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Alternative, you could just redefine the Kernel system method:

```
module Kernel
  def system(cmd)
    "call #{cmd}"
  end
end

> system("test")
=> "call test"
```

And the credit goes to this question: [Mock system call in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628586/mock-system-call-in-ruby)

Comment: Why does this answer get so many downvotes? The answer that @jpatokal refers to has 17 upvotes!

Comment: Presumably because it's not stubbing/mocking, but actually *replacing* the method.  Then again, would you ever want to make actual system calls in tests?