# How would I test a ruby method that only calls a system command?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

After looking at:

[How do I stub/mock a call to the command line with rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708661/how-do-i-stub-mock-a-call-to-the-command-line-with-rspec)

The answer provided is:

```
require "rubygems"
require "spec"

class Dummy
  def command_line
    system("ls")
  end
end

describe Dummy do
  it  "command_line should call ls" do
    d = Dummy.new
    d.should_receive("system").with("ls")
    d.command_line
  end
end
```

My question is: **How does that actually test anything?**

By making a method to that says "call the ls command on the system", and then writing a test that says "my method should call the ls command on the system", **how does that provide any benefit**?

If the method were to change, I would have to change the test as well, but I'm not sure I see the added benefit.

Comment: Ok, now imagine that it's not you that changes the line of code thinking "it won't matter if I call 'dir' instead of 'ls' (or whatever)... they get a failing test and think to themselves "oh, we were expecting that I call ls in that method, I wonder why?" which you will of course have made obvious in your commenting. ;)

Comment: Also: yeah, the given example is clearly a toy-example that is very simple and almost not worth testing... but most of your tests won't be this simple.

Comment: The reason I ask is because my example really is that simple. I have implemented a new SCM for Capistrano. My custom SCM class has some methods that just call some simple system commands. (The equivalent of "git clone" for example). I could write a test that ensures that "git clone" gets called, but I don't see the value in it. If someone else in the future needs to change that method, then they also need to change the test. But the test only checks that the command was called. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, so there are pros and cons for both options: on the one hand, it seems a lot of fuss for a single line of code. On the other hand if somebody later changes your method to be more complex, no test fails - and people that are used to "if a test breaks I'll change it" might not realise that they actually need to add a test at all.On the gripping hand, setting a behaviour-expectation on *yourself* to always add a test (even if it seems so useless) can be a very good habit to have...

Comment: because you are also working with the fact that you must remember to write tests for important code... and if you allow exceptions in your own behaviour, then you also allow the possibility for you to forget to write a test on more important code. IMO I think it's worth doing - for the latter two reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are describing is known as the "mockist" or "London" school of unit testing. It's benefits include

- That the act of constructing such a test creates an incentive to design units which are not excessively complex in terms of their dependencies or conditional logic
- That such tests execute very quickly, which can be very important for large systems
- That such tests can be reasonably built to provide maximal coverage for the unit under test
- That such tests provide a "vise" of sorts around your code such that inadvertent changes will result in a failing test

Of course, such tests have their limitations, which is why they are often paired with system level tests which test whether a collection of units operating together achieve some higher order outcome.