# How do I mock Perl's built-in backticks operator?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, backticks, qx

I'd like to unit test a Perl program of mine that is using backticks. Is there a way to mock the backticks so that they would do something different from executing the external command?

[Another question shows what I need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628586/mock-system-call-in-ruby/1628848), but in Ruby. Unfortunately, I cannot choose to use Ruby for this project, nor do I want to avoid the backticks.

Comment: Can you clarify "I do not want to avoid the backticks"?

Comment: Vaguely related to this - I often write a things using system, or backtics then realise I want to check what command I am puitting out. I have thought of crating a diagnostic version of system.

Comment: @justintime: patching IPC::System::Simple to use a $DEBUG flag would be very welcome, I think.

Comment: You say "Ha Ha Ha, you are a stupid built-in."  It annoys it to no end.

Comment: "nor do I want to avoid the backticks". Why do people care so much about the syntax they use? Why is it so important to use backticks over writing a couple more lines in a subroutine to do what you need, or even to use a module like Git::Wrapper?

Comment: @Ether, @brian d foy: I wrote this to clarify my requirements. The question would be rather easy to answer if "system" were used or some other method instead of backticks, because one can easily replace a built-in method (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Overriding-Built-in-Functions)
Do I care much about the syntax? Not really... although programming is always a quest for the most beautiful solution.

Comment: Why not just not use backticks? Or wrap backticks?

Comment: "Why not just not use backticks?"... what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can<sup>*</sup> mock the built-in [`readpipe`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#readpipe) function. Perl will call your mock function when it encounters a backticks or `qx` expression.

```
BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::readpipe = \&mock_readpipe
};

sub mock_readpipe {
  wantarray ? ("foo\n") : "foo\n";
}

print readpipe("ls -R");
print `ls -R`;
print qx(ls -R);
```

---

```
$ perl mock-readpipe.pl
foo
foo
foo
```

<sup>*</sup> - if you have [perl version 5.8.9](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.2/pod/perl589delta.pod#readpipe_is_now_overridable) or later.

Comment: This seems to only work right in later perls. 5.8.8 only prints foo for `readpipe(...)` and not backticks or `qx`.  Works as shown in 5.10.1

Comment: Good catch Eric. This was changed in 5.8.9: http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.2/pod/perl589delta.pod#readpipe_is_now_overridable

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using backticks, you can use `capture` from [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::System::Simple), and then write a mock version of capture() in your unit test.

```
# application
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture);
my $stuff = capture("some command");

# test script
{
     package IPC::System::Simple;
     sub capture
     {
         # do something else; perhaps a call to ok()
     }
}

# ... rest of unit test here
```

Comment: If you are going to call a subroutine, just write your own wrapper so you don't have to mock at all.